Are there any ways to reduce the space complexity of the simplex method when dealing with totally unimodular (TU) matrices?
I am try to solve a problem with a strict space complexity and time complexity(60mb and 1s). I use the simplex method, but it requires significant space complexity, reaching up to $O(nm)$.
However, since the matrix in the simplex method is totally unimodular (TU), during the simplex iterations, the matrix will only contain values of $\pm1$ and $0$. Given the large number of $0$s in the matrix, I find this to be quite wasteful. Are there any strategies to optimize the memory usage and avoid this kind of waste?
I just try to solve it by sparse matrix, is there a proof about it space usage? Thanks so much.

Do you mean "space complexity"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity  What are you counting as the space complexity?  Are you counting the input as part of the space complexity?  Are you familiar with standard methods for storing a sparse matrix?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix  I encourage you to [edit] your question to provide more context and explain in more detail what you are asking and what approaches you've already considered and why you've rejected them.
